# unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address

Tags: c, linux, freertos, zynq

I am experiencing a difficult time trying to get things working with a project using a Zynq 7000 and having a remoteproc connection between the two cortex A9 cores (one running freeRTOS and the other Linux). I am sending information through rpmsg from the Linux side to freeRTOS through an application that I run several times. After several executions, I get the following error:

```
[22/6 14:05] Ros Gorka
reading scheduling configuration
Parsing started. Populating basic fields
parsing DL_flows
pars[  716.752328] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address c0642bec
[  716.764902] pgd = eea74000
[  716.767591] [c0642bec] *pgd=0061940e(bad)
[  716.771588] Internal error: Oops: 80d [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[  716.777052] Modules linked in: 8021q rpmsg_user_dev_driver(O) virtio_rpmsg_bus rpmsg_char rpmsg_core zynq_remoteproc remoteproc virtio_ring virtio
[  716.790164] CPU: 0 PID: 2521 Comm: main Tainted: G           O    4.14.0-g622cead-dirty #45
[  716.798491] Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[  716.803006] task: ef1f19c0 task.stack: ef044000
[  716.807532] PC is at try_module_get+0x58/0xc0
[  716.811860] LR is at 0xebf31ec0
[  716.814985] pc : [<c01843c0>]    lr : [<ebf31ec0>]    psr: a0010013
[  716.821234] sp : ef045df0  ip : ebf31ebf  fp : ee47ef00
[  716.826442] r10: 00000000  r9 : 00000002  r8 : 00000006
[  716.831651] r7 : ee47ef00  r6 : ee915ae8  r5 : c0642a24  r4 : ee407d98
[  716.838160] r3 : c0642a24  r2 : c0642bec  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 00000001
[  716.844672] Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none
[  716.851788] Control: 18c5387d  Table: 2ea7404a  DAC: 00000051
[  716.857517] Process main (pid: 2521, stack limit = 0xef044210)
[  716.863332] Stack: (0xef045df0 to 0xef046000)
[  716.867676] 5de0:                                     a80d29e0 ef045ed8 ee407d98 c01f2ea0
[  716.875837] 5e00: c0c68450 ee407d98 ee915ae8 c01f3200 00000802 ef045f74 ee47ef00 ee915ae8
[  716.883996] 5e20: ee47ef08 c01f31cc 00000006 c01ebbe8 ef045ed0 00000000 00000802 00000000
[  716.892155] 5e40: 00000006 00000002 00000000 c01fcb8c ee44f738 c01d0610 00000000 ee47ef00
[  716.900314] 5e60: 00000041 ef045ed8 014200ca ffffe000 b6f0c000 c09a78a4 eea76db8 00000000
[  716.908473] 5e80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002 ee915ae8 ee85e110 ee01f220 ef045fb0
[  716.916633] 5ea0: ef1f19c0 ee44f700 80000007 00000003 ef045f74 00000001 fffff000 c0107b44
[  716.924791] 5ec0: ef044000 00000000 00000000 c01fe530 ee85e110 ee01f220 a80d29e0 00000006
[  716.932951] 5ee0: ef0e7015 00000000 00000000 eecfc550 ee915ae8 00000101 00000002 0000005c
[  716.941110] 5f00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 ef045f10 ffffffff 00000000 ef054000 00000000
[  716.949269] 5f20: 00000000 ef0e7000 00000003 eea0b000 eeb8c4c0 00000000 00000400 c020cba8
[  716.957428] 5f40: ef0e7000 00000000 ffffff9c 00000002 ffffff9c c0107b44 00000003 ffffff9c
[  716.965587] 5f60: ef0e7000 c01ecf20 ee58ea80 00000000 00000000 00000802 00000000 00000006
[  716.973746] 5f80: 00000100 00000001 ef045f9c 00000001 000013ad b6ef4000 00000005 c0107b44
[  716.981906] 5fa0: ef044000 c0107980 00000001 000013ad 0000fea8 00000802 2fdf7200 be9d81ec
[  716.990065] 5fc0: 00000001 000013ad b6ef4000 00000005 00000000 00000000 b6fa1000 00000000
[  716.998224] 5fe0: 00000000 be9d8194 00009a83 b6e9a5f6 40010030 0000fea8 00000000 00000000
[  717.006397] [<c01843c0>] (try_module_get) from [<c01f2ea0>] (cdev_get+0x1c/0x50)
[  717.013765] [<c01f2ea0>] (cdev_get) from [<c01f3200>] (chrdev_open+0x34/0x178)
[  717.020976] [<c01f3200>] (chrdev_open) from [<c01ebbe8>] (do_dentry_open.constprop.4+0x128/0x314)
[  717.029824] [<c01ebbe8>] (do_dentry_open.constprop.4) from [<c01fcb8c>] (path_openat+0x53c/0x10d0)
[  717.038762] [<c01fcb8c>] (path_openat) from [<c01fe530>] (do_filp_open+0x60/0xc4)
[  717.046229] [<c01fe530>] (do_filp_open) from [<c01ecf20>] (do_sys_open+0x160/0x1e0)
[  717.053872] [<c01ecf20>] (do_sys_open) from [<c0107980>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
[  717.061590] Code: e192cf9f e13c0001 0a000003 e08ce000 (e1824f9e)
[  717.067661] ---[ end trace 207b2417ca0bb59f ]---
ing UL_flows
parsing completed with no errors
[  717.072372] note: main[2521] exited with preempt_count 2
Segmentation fault
```

At first I thought it was something to do with freeing memory resources after each time, but I checked it by running `top` command and everything seems to be fine. I don't have much experience working with rpmsg/remoteproc on linux. If someone could give me some guidelines on how to fix the problem I would appreciate it. And if something is missing don't mind to ask.